# phpQuery get attr from an empty tag

Tags: phpquery

I have a problem that annoys me pretty much. I'm grabbing some content from a web page using combination of cURL and phpQuery.

In the page I'm fetching, there is following code that determines post rating:

```
<div class="post">
    <ul id="thumb_ul" class="star-rating" style="width:60px;">
        <li class="current-rating" style="width:0px;"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using phpQuery as follows:

```
$pqD = phpQuery::newDocument($buffer);
foreach(pq('div.post') as $li) {
    $rating = pq($li)->find('ul > li.current-rating')->attr('style');
}
```

Ratings are, obviously, defined in `<li>` tag, in `style` attribute. I thought of accessing it with `pq($li)->find('ul > li.current-rating')->attr('style')` and I expected to get `width:0px` as a result.
Ratings are defined as follows: 0-0, 12-1, 24-2, ..., 60-6.

However, phpQuery doesn's seem very much 'interested' in an empty tag. For every other thing that I'm grabbing from page, it works well.

Any ideas?
Thx

Comment: you may need to update your phpQuery to the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

*FULL TEST SOURCE:* (copy and test)

```
<?php
require_once('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');

$buffer = '
   <div class="post">
    <ul id="thumb_ul" class="star-rating" style="width:60px;">
        <li class="current-rating" style="width:0px;"></li>
         <li class="current-rating" style="width:6px;"></li>
          <li class="current-rating" style="width:8px;"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
';

$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($buffer);
foreach ($doc['.post ul li.current-rating'] as $li) {
  $rating .= pq($li)->attr('style');
    // or $rating[] .=  if you need an array()  
}

echo $rating; //ouput: width:0px;width:6px;width:8px;
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your reponse, but that leaves me with same results - none :)

Comment: I'm very sorry for not assigning that +50 to you. Turned out that stackoverflow showed me info about your comment too late :(

Comment: BTW, you were right! :) The problem wasn't in my phpQuery version, but you answer and example you posted directed me towards the solution -> it turned out that I changed the buffer with html :)